# Add triangle to side of div with css

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add a triangle to the side of my current `li` in the menu. I set it up so I can edit the css of it with jquery, and want to know if it's possible to achieve this affect by editing the border on the `li` instead of adding a new div.

[jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/py3BU/) I would like to get look of the second div by just adding borders to `div-1`

```
<div class="div-1"></div>
<br>
<div class="div-1"><div><div class="triangle"></div>

.div-1 {
    width:174px;
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#149dae;
}
.triangle {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 16px 0 16px 16px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #149dae;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:174px;
}
```

Comment: for styling purpose use pseudoelements instead of empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed your `div-1` fix that and 
then change `display` property of `div-1` to `inline-block` as value and `display:inline` for `triangle` div.

That's it. it works.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mirage_ak/py3BU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/py3BU/4/
I have edited your code. This is what you were looking for? A triangle comes to side of the div which you hover.

Here's the code.

html code.

```
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <br>
  <br /><div class="div-1"></div>
```

Here is the CSS code

```
.div-1 
{
    width:174px;
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#149dae;
}

 .div-1:hover 
 {
   width:158px;
   height: 0px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 16px 0 16px 16px;
   border-color: transparent transparent transparent #85b375;
 }
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another div or element is necessary to get triangle shape inside another if you are not using a background image. Otherwise adding background image to li with a triangle shape which you want would be a clever idea.